# How is the input to a BROUWER algorithm done

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, fixed-point

The Brouwer fixpoint theorem states that any continuous mapping $f$, from a convex, compact set to itself will contain a fixpoint.

The Brouwer algorithm finds these (approximate) fixpoints. But how is a continuous function inputted into this algorithm?

Is it as a black box? If so, would changing this to a discrete set of points change the complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: What is the Brouwer algorithm?  Where did you encounter it?

Comment: @D.W. I am referring to an algorithm that can compute Brouwer fixpoints. I read about this problem when looking into the PPAD complexity class. An example reference is [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4568294). There is also a mathoverflow question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105883/can-we-actually-find-any-fixed-points-with-brouwers-theorem)

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your question to provide background to make this understandable for others.  Explain what you are reading, provide a full citation (not just a link), and summarize whichever algorithm you are thinking of.  I also encourage you to merge all your accounts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to formalize the BROUWER problem. The most intuitive is to have $f$ specified by an arithmetic circuit, as in Etessami and Yannakakis, [On the complexity of Nash equilibria and other fixed points](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/kousha/nash_focs07_full_j_spec_issue_sub.pdf). However, this version is not known to lie in PPAD (see [this tutorial](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/kousha/dagstuhl14-etessami-tutorial-equilibrium.pdf) of Etessami).

To fix this, we can either restrict the circuit to be piecewise linear, as in Etessami and Yannakakis; or ask that the function be Lipschitz with an explicit constant, as in Rubinstein, [Settling the complexity of computing approximate two-player Nash equilibria](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04550.pdf); or use a discretization which corresponds to a (highly restricted) piecewise linear function, as in Daskalakis, Goldberg and Papadimitriou, [The complexity of computing a Nash equilibrium](https://people.csail.mit.edu/costis/journal_ver10.pdf).